# What is the correct way to convert a Vec for FFI without reallocation?

Tags: vector, rust, ffi

I need to pass a `Vec` of elements across the FFI. Experimenting, I came across a few interesting points. I started with giving the FFI all 3: `ptr`, `len` and `capacity` so that I could reconstruct the `Vec` to destroy it later:

```
let ptr = vec.as_mut_ptr();
let len = vec.len();
let cap = vec.capacity();
mem::forget(vec);
extern_fn(ptr, len, cap);

// ...

pub unsafe extern "C" fn free(ptr: *mut u8, len: usize, cap: usize) {
    let _ = Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, cap);
}
```

I wanted to get rid of `capacity` as it's useless to my frontend; it's just so that I can reconstruct my vector to free the memory.

`Vec::shrink_to_fit()` is tempting as it seems to eliminate the need of dealing with capacity. Unfortunately, the documentation on it does not guarantee that it'll make `len == capacity`, hence I assume that during `from_raw_parts()` will likely trigger Undefined Behavior.

`into_boxed_slice()` seems to have a guarantee that it's going to make `len == capacity` from the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice), so I used that next. ***Please correct me if I'm wrong***. The problem is that it does not seem to guarantee no-reallocation. Here is a simple program:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    v.push(100u8);
    v.push(110);
    let ptr_1 = v.as_mut_ptr();
    let mut boxed_slice = v.into_boxed_slice();
    let ptr_2 = boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr();
    let ptr_3 = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice);
    println!("{:?}. {:?}. {:?}", ptr_1, ptr_2, ptr_3);
}
```

[In the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3Awith_capacity(1000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20v.push(100u8)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20v.push(110)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr_1%20%3D%20v.as_mut_ptr()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20boxed_slice%20%3D%20v.into_boxed_slice()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr_2%20%3D%20boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr_3%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Ainto_raw(boxed_slice)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D.%20%7B%3A%3F%7D.%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20ptr_1%2C%20ptr_2%2C%20ptr_3)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0), It prints:

```
rustc 1.14.0 (e8a012324 2016-12-16)
0x7fdc9841b000. 0x7fdc98414018. 0x7fdc98414018
```

This is not good if it has to find new memory instead of being able to shed off extra capacity without causing a copy.

Is there any other way I can pass my vector across the FFI (to C) and not pass capacity? It seems `into_boxed_slice()` is what I need, but why does it involve re-allocation and copying data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is relatively simple.

Modern memory allocators will segregate allocations in "sized" slabs, where each slab is responsible for dealing with a given range of sizes. For example:

- 8 bytes slab: anything from 1 to 8 bytes
- 16 bytes slab: anything from 9 to 16 bytes
- 24 bytes slab: anything from 17 to 24 bytes
- ...

When you allocate memory, you ask for a given size, the allocator finds the right slab, gets a chunk from it, and returns your pointer.

When you deallocate memory... how do you expect the allocator to find the right slab? There are 2 solutions:

- the allocator has a way to search for the slab that contains your range of memory, somehow, which involves either a linear search through the slabs or some kind of global look-up table or ...
- *you* tell the allocator what was the size of the allocated block

It's obvious here that the C interface (`free`, `realloc`) is rather sub-par, and therefore Rust wishes to use the more efficient interface instead, the one where the onus is on the caller.

---

So, you have two choices:

1. Pass the capacity
2. Ensure that the length and the capacity are equal

As you realized, (2) may require a *new* allocation, which is quite undesirable. (1) can be implemented either by passing the capacity the whole way, or stash it at some point then retrieve it when you need it.

That's it. You have to evaluate your trade-offs.

Comment: Gonna be stealing some of this for addition to the Omnibus ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Feel free :)

Comment: Right and it also seems to be consistent with C++ which has capacity and len too - `resize` does not alter capacity and there and `shrink_to_fit` is an unbinding request - just like here - so probably passing the capacity along is the best way. Thanks.