# How to get Rust Vec buffer?

Tags: rust

I want to dynamically allocate an array at runtime, so I use Vec to implement it. And I want to use a raw pointer to point the array address, like this:

```rust
fn alloc(&mut page: Page) {
    page.data = vec![0; page.page_size].as_mut_ptr();//it's a Vec<u8>
}
```

I want to know if the pointer directly points to the vec buffer, and the length is exactly the `page.page_size`?

The effect I want to have is just like the following C code:

```c
void alloc(Page* page) {
    page->data = (u8*)malloc(page->page_size);
}
```

Comment: `vec![0 as u8; page.page_size];` Is more reliable to set its size to page_size of `u8`

Comment: Please give some thought to how you're going to free that memory when you're done with it, because you need [both a length and capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723826/what-is-the-correct-way-to-convert-a-vec-for-ffi-without-reallocation) to do so. If the buffer never needs to be resized, you might use `into_boxed_slice` + `Box::into_raw` to obviate the need for capacity (but you still need length).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only guarantee you get from `vec` in this case, when it is created by `new()` or `vec![]` macro is it will have reserved at least page_size bytes of data. To reserve exact amount of bytes create it with `Vec::with_capacity()`.

When working with raw pointers it is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure the data lives long enough. In this example the `vec` will only live within `alloc` so when your function return the address it will free the buffer at the same time.

Comment: `Vec::with_capacity` would only reserve, `vec![T;n]` creates a vector of *length* `n`, its capacity may or may not be exactly that (odds are it is but I've not looked).

Comment: Thanks, that was my understanding as well, in this case the later is used.

Comment: "You could probably solve this with some lifetime annotations" - no, they couldn't. Lifetimes never change the semantics of generated code, they exist only to check if the code is correct. To make buffer alive after the function it is created in returns, one must either store it somewhere, or explicitly leak it.

Comment: Thanks, TIL. So in this case we need to bind the life of the vector to page by storing it there otherwise `alloc` will always return leaked or free-ed memory blocks.

Comment: I thought when I call the method `as_mut_ptr`, I would take the responsibility of cleaning up the memory. 

In this case, what should I do to make the vector live as long as I want?

Comment: I read this https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_ptr as you must save the vec to be able to keep the buffer

Comment: @LunarEclipse https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts works as you described